# iOS - Hosting JSON file to parse it using URL

Tags: ios, json, rest, web-hosting

I have a .json file with valid data. I want to host it online and use the live url in my app. I tried putting the json file in drop box and tried to verify the json data on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com site but it shows "JSON data URL does not contain JSON data"  Is there any other way can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: So, you have valid JSON data, something is telling you you don't, and you aren't sharing the JSON?

Comment: Have you generated the share link so you can indeed access this as plain text from visiting a URL

Comment: @nil https://www.dropbox.com/s/okspzncwy8f5vld/reports.json

Comment: You need to share the raw data URL, not the Dropbox share link. I'm not sure how to do it, tho.

Comment: @agarie thats what the question is..

Comment: Just get hosting and put it there. This is not what Dropbox is for.

Comment: I was told it could be done. But right now hosting seems like the only solution..Thanks

Comment: Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50667231/1179638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so you want to host a static JSON file on a webserver so an iOS app can open and parse it. There are a couple of steps and a slight learning curve but from what I'm reading this may help you.

**Step 1:** Verify that your JSON is valid since it appears that there's some confusion. Open the JSON in a text-editor like notepad. Copy it and paste it in the text area at this site:

> http://jsonlint.com/

If you get a parse error - find the line and edit. If you can't do this or the JSON is valid - stop and resolve this problem.

**Step 2:**
While you could use dropbox to do this its not a good idea for a real app.  Get a web host.  Depending on your basic skill level you can use a cloud provider like Amazon, Heroku, etc.  Based on this question - I'd recommend a basic ftp site.  There are a ton of free/cheap webhosts.

> https://www.google.com/search?q=cheap+web+hosting

The only thing you'll want to watch out with a "free plan" for is that they don't inject ads into your pages.  (I'm looking at you GoDaddy.)

**Step 3:** (assuming you have an iOS app setup)

Add AFNetworking to your project and set up a AFJSONOperation.

> http://afnetworking.com/

And use the following code:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.foo.com/bar.json"];

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);


    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        NSLog(@"error: %@ response: %@", error, response);


    }];

[operation start];
```

**Edit:** removed link to Dropbox article.  Added cheap webhost options.

Comment: Thanks. I used x10 web hosting and its working fine now. Thanks for detailed explanation..

Answer (score 18):

You can still use Dropbox if you don't want to pay for a hosting provider or if you just want to test your app before paying for one.

To do this, you need to replace the `www.dropbox.com` part of the URL with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` as is said in [this Dropbox article](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en).

I'm mainly leaving this answer for the future, as this can be useful for other people (me included).

Answer (score 18):

This is exactly the problem I wanted to solve with http://www.myjson.com
An easy and simple solution to hosting JSON.

Comment: Very elegant solution indeed. thanks Lance.

Comment: That's a very unsafe approach. As far as I understand anybody can modify anybody else's JSON.

Comment: does myjson.com support editting JSON on same URL ??

Comment: @AshishSajwan I think no.  Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50667231/1179638

Answer (score 4):

You can save your JSON here https://quarkbackend.com - free json hosting

This tool let you manage your files and the urls will not change after updating the file

Comment: You are Awesome..

Answer (score 2):

Other than `myjson.com`, You can host it in `pastebin.com` and use the "`Raw`" link to access it. Once advantage of `pastebin.com` over `myjson.com` is that you can set a expiry period after which it will be auto deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Drop box is not an ideal solution for this. I would use S3 or something of that nature.

Comment: There are a bunch of good resources for this, here is one: http://chadthompson.me/2013/05/06/static-web-hosting-with-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Create a GitHub [Gist](http://gist.github.com/) account.

**Step 2:** Create a new Gist file with your JSON content and get the raw URL

For Instance:
"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME/0df1fa45aa11753de0a85893448b22de/raw/YourData.txt";

**Step 3:** Retrieve the file contents from your app by invoking the WebService in GET request mode.